# clicking on play button does not pause the song

Tags: javascript, dom

I have assigned a single icon for both play and pause. If it clicks one-time song will play and again clicked song should pause. But the issue is song gets played but not getting paused.

```
var  flag=0; 

document.querySelector(".play").addEventListener("click",function(){
    
    if(flag==0)
    {
        alert("button clicked");
    var sng=new Audio("music/1.mp3");
    sng.play()
    flag=1;
    }
    
    else
    {
        sng.pause();
        flag=0;

    }

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sng` variable isn't reachable inside the `else` clause. Declare it in the top scope:

```js
var flag = 0;
var sng = new Audio("music/1.mp3");

document.querySelector(".play").addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (flag == 0) {
    alert("button clicked");
    sng.play()
    flag = 1;
  } else {
    sng.pause();
    flag = 0;
  }
})
```

Or this tidied up version that accomplishes the same thing:

```js
const sng = new Audio("https://cdn.pixabay.com/download/audio/2022/05/27/audio_1808fbf07a.mp3?filename=lofi-study-112191.mp3");
const playButton = document.querySelector(".play")

const toggleSong = () => sng.paused ? sng.play() : sng.pause()

playButton.addEventListener("click", () => toggleSong())
```

```html
<button class="play">Play/pause</button>
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. It is working. I have a doubt even if we declare a variable with the var keyword inside the function will the scope will be valid throughout the function? Also, can I call the function inside the event listener and write it separately not like writing function in the event listener itself

Comment: @ATHULSURESH I revised my answer with a tidied up version that should answer your latter question. As for `var` scope, I suggest you [read up on scopes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var), but generally speaking I recommend using `let` and `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: @ATHULSURESH If I answered your question, feel free to mark it as the answer. :)